# Segmentaion fault possible because of map

Tags: c++, dictionary, segmentation-fault

I wrote a code which has to take two string as input. It has to output number of steps(adjacent letter flips or flipping first and last letter) it takes one word to convert to another. It gives correct values till the size of string is 8. If the size of string is more than 8, it gives segmentation fault. I could not find any mistake. Can anyone please help me out. Thanks in advance. This is the code:

```
map<string,int>imap;

int easyStrings(string a, string b) {

    //cout<<a<<endl;
    if(a.compare(b) == 0)
        return 0;

    map<string,int>::iterator it = imap.find(a);
    if(it != imap.end())
        return it->second;

    imap.insert(pair<string,int>(a,-2));

    int min = -2;

    string str = a;


    str[0] = a[a.length()-1];
    str[a.length()-1] = a[0];

    it = imap.find(str);
    if(it == imap.end() || it->second != -2)
        min = 1 + easyStrings(str,b); 

    for(int i = 0 ; i < a.length()-1; i++)
    {
        string check = a;
        check[i] = a[i+1];
        check[i+1] = a[i];

        int steps = 0;
        it = imap.find(check);
        if(it == imap.end() || it->second != -2)    
        {
            steps = 1 + easyStrings(check,b);

            if(steps < min || min ==-2)
                if(steps > 0)
                    min = steps;
        }

    }

    imap[a] = min;
    return min; 
}
```

I tried using debugger. I shows error in imap.insert(pair(a,-2));. It also gives a huge trace showing problems mainly with malloc.

It does not go into infinite recursion. There are factorial of length of input string at maximum and I only insert a string when it is not found in map.

Comment: Well, have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see where the exception is happening?

Comment: Are you certain that you have enough RAM to handle a recursive depth of 8 nPr 8? Every time you call `easyStrings` you are using up more and more heap space with all the new strings you declare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cursory glance at this function with gdb reveals that this function is recursive, and that strings over a certain length trigger it to enter infinite-depth recursion (or at least a depth that 4 gigs of RAM can't handle). I would look at your recursion conditionals and double check that there is an exit case that will be met for all of them.

Comment: It does not go into infinite loop but I feel not enough memory to allocate is a only possible reason. Thank you.